# can a Custom Driver control Printer Motors?

Tags: c++, printing, driver, linux-device-driver, hardware

I want to write a driver to control several aspects of my epson printer: e.g. the position of the printer head, and the other motors involved in moving the paper. The ultimate goal is to be able to build a CNC-type machine out of the printer with **minimal/no** modification of the printer hardware and **without the addition of additional microcontrolers**.

I've had this goal for a long time, and am just about to begin reading books on drivers to start this project. **Is this goal possible?**

(For reference, I am planning to do my project on Linux, using an Epson WorkForce WF-M1030 Monochrome Inkjet Printer...however, I think my question applies more generally to the ability to control printer hardware via computer drivers. )

Comment: The answer to your topic question is **yes**.

Comment: That's depends if these features are controlled by a device driver. I seriously doubt that. the firmware on the printer usually handles this stuff.